# AJAX Dropbox can't open uploaded file

Tags: javascript, ajax, dropbox

I uploaded a file on Dropbox using this code :

```
function DropUpload(file) {
    // ... file selected from a file <input>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
        type: 'post',
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer <Here was the access Token>",
            "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/' +file + '","mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            document.write('i did it\n');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error(data);
            document.write('Oh no');
        }

    })
}
```

It worked, my file got uploaded but I can't open it and when I download it the file still can't be opened. I also noticed that the size isn't right either (a lot smaller than the original) and Dropbox says that the format is accepted but a problem occured.
So the question is simple : What did I do wrong ?

EDIT : As asked in the comments, here is the whole code

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                               
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                        
    <head>                                                                                                                                                                                    
        <script src="get_from_cin7.js"></script>                                                                                                                                              
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                              
    </head>                                                                                                                                                                                   
    <body>                                                                                                                                                                                    
        <script>DropUpload("Images/sky.jpg");</script>                                                                                                                                        
    </body>                                                                                                                                                                                   
</html>
```

Comment: Before someone asks, yes I searched on my own and I did research on the internet, but everytime someone encounters this problem it happens on a line that doesn't look like anything I did

Comment: I still don't know why ajax does that and can't seem to find my awnser anywhere

Comment: Could you add the rest of the relevant code, showing what `file` is and where it comes from? I see you're using it the same way in two places, but that looks incorrect. The `data` parameter should be the file data you want to upload, but the `path` parameter inside the `Dropbox-API-Arg` header should be the path and name where you want to upload the file (not also the file data itself).

Comment: I'll add those infos right now

Comment: Well, I can't open my files right now so It'll have to wait for a bit

Comment: Ok I edited the question and I added the whole code. The file sent is just a random image, but whatever I send does the same thing. It doesn't matter what type of file is sent

Comment: I see from the comment in `DropUpload` that `file` is supposed to be `selected from a file <input>`, however when you're actually calling `DropUpload`, you're just passing in a string ("Images/sky.jpg") not an actual file object. You should update your code to pass in an actual file object, and then you presumably want to use something like `file.name` instead of just `file` as the `path` inside `Dropbox-API-Arg`.

Comment: Thank you @Greg . Could you please post this as the awnser so other people who have the same problem know what I did wrong ? Thanks again, you really elped me there